# How to average several posteriors distributions from a Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: r, bayesian, monte-carlo, posterior, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

Say you produce several posteriors distributions from different runs of the same model under different seeds. That is to say you have something like the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(10100101)
N <- 150;R <- 25
normals <- lapply(1:R,function(x){rnorm(n = N, mean = 0, sd   = 1)})
df <- data.frame(Reduce(cbind, normals))
colnames(df) <- 1:ncol(df)
df2 <- stack(df)
ggplot(df2, aes(values, fill = ind)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.000001) + theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

I would like to add to the plot the "average posterior" produced by the different runs of my model. At first I thought that I would be as easy as to apply the mean of the posteriors. However, I am getting something that converges to zero because I am simply averaging values that came from a standard normal distribution as you can see in the picture below:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(10100101)
N <- 150;R <- 25
normals <- lapply(1:R,function(x){rnorm(n = N, mean = 0, sd   = 1)})
df <- data.frame(Reduce(cbind, normals))
colnames(df) <- 1:ncol(df)
df$mean <- rowMeans(df) # <- this is the average I am generating
df2 <- stack(df)
ggplot(df2, aes(values, fill = ind)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.000001) +theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Finally, my questions is how to **correctly** average the posteriors generated by my model under different seeds.

Comment: What would you expect? The arithmetic average of the posterior over different samples all simulated from the same $N(0,1)$ sampling distribution is proportional in the limit to$$\pi(\theta)\int\exp\{-n(x-\theta)^2/2\}\,\exp\{-nx^2/2\}\,\text dx$$

Comment: Your code is averaging the *random variables,* whereas you want to average their *densities.*  To see the difference, concatenate all the values you produce and draw their histogram.

Comment: Thank you very much @whuber, as always, you spotted the solution right away. One last question, the correct term to refer to this average is the _"mean density"_ of my posteriors, right?

Comment: That sounds like a good description.  I would be careful about the computation, though, because you need to *weight* the densities by the numbers of observations in each run when you average.  Think about an extreme case where one of your runs is extremely short: the bin densities may randomly range from zero through high values and you don't want this to mess up the densities observed over the other much longer runs.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @[whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) comment. The solution is found by averaging the entire vector of posteriors (of all runs) which allows me to average the *densities* not the *random variables* as I did in my original question.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(10100101)
N <- 150;R <- 25
normals <- lapply(1:R,function(x){rnorm(n = N, mean = 0, sd   = 1)})
df <- data.frame(Reduce(cbind, normals))
colnames(df) <- 1:ncol(df)
df2 <- stack(df)

ggplot() +
  geom_density(data = df2, aes(x = values, fill = ind), alpha = 0) +
  geom_density(data = df2, aes(x = values), alpha = 0.3, colour="red",size=1.5)  + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]